# image and description side by side in div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery code which is as follows.

```
for(i = 0; i<n ; i++)
{
    $('#gameContentDiv').append('<div sytle="float:left"><a href='+json.results[i].site_detail_url+' target="_blank"> <img src="' + json.results[i].image.medium_url + '" alt=Image /></a></div>');
     $('#gameContentDiv').append(description);
}
```

I want the Image and description to be side by side. 
(Description has to be top right of the image).

Comment: That really has nothing to do with javascript, and should probably be done by placing it where you want it in the CSS.

Comment: `sytle` is misspelled and should be `style`. To be on top use absolute positioning and adjust z-index accordingly

Comment: Yeah, style was misspelled and I was banging my head for whole day :). It worked.